# Mail merge to PDF rather than Print

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I used the tutorial from Spreadsheet Page Excel Tips: Mail Merge - Without Word to create a mail merge style report for 100 records. Using the record index and indirect lookups from another worksheet all work great to generate the reports I need.

Rather than print, I am looking to save each output as a PDF named using a field in the merge. I tried to replace the "ActiveSheet.PrintOut" with "ActiveSheet.ExportasFixedFormat" and entered the PDF specifications. It worked to a certain extent in that I was able to generate a PDF to the specified location but it would only generate one PDF rather than the whole range I was trying to create.

Here is the code I am trying to use. I have looked through other answers for how to loop through each record to create individual PDFs but haven't been able to generate more than the single PDF at a time.

```
Public Const APPNAME As String = "Progress Report"

Option Explicit

Sub PrintForms()
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim HRETID As String
    Dim i As Integer

Sheets("ProgressReport").Activate
StartRow = Range("StartRow")
EndRow = Range("EndRow")
HRETID = Range("HRETID")

 If StartRow > EndRow Then
    Msg = "ERROR" & vbCrLf & "The starting row must be less than the ending row!"
    MsgBox Msg, vbCritical, APPNAME
End If

For i = StartRow To EndRow
    Range("RowIndex") = i
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\ewilliamson\PDFs\" & HRETID, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you want the PDF file name to come from?

Comment: `Filename:="C:\Users\ewilliamson\PDFs\" & HRETID & i & ".pdf"` will at least give you numbered copies

Comment: Ultimately, I would like the filename to be "HRETID_Date.pdf". The "HRETID" field is an indirect lookup from another sheet based in the "Current Record" index and changes with each row in the range. I removed the HRETID and just used the "i" variable and it worked to generate the pdfs I needed but they are just numbered sequentially. If there is a way to include the HRETID based on the i variable and include that in the filename, I'd be all set. Thanks!

Comment: `Filename:="C:\Users\ewilliamson\PDFs\" & Range("HRETID").Value & ".pdf"` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your filename to be dynamic then you need to pick up the value from `HRETID` within the loop, instead of just once outside of the loop:

```
For i = StartRow To EndRow
    Range("RowIndex") = i
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\ewilliamson\PDFs\" & _
                   Range("HRETID").Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value of HRETID in your filename:= assignment is not changing. (To do so, it would need to be assigned a new value for each row in your loop)

If you want to loop through a column to assign the value of the cells in that column to HRETID then try this:

```
Dim rItem as Range

for each ritem in Range("HRETID")
   ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\ewilliamson\PDFs\" & ritem.value , _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False

next rItem
```

Note you do not need HRETID as a string because you can get the cells value from rItem.

Comment: The sheet is constructed to use the rowindex and an indirect lookup from another sheet to compile information into a report format. HRETID is one of the variables looked up from the other sheet. I was able to generate numbered PDFs using @Tim Williams response above, now I just need to switch out the "i" for the different "HRETID" values that are looked up. I might be using "range" improperly.